# Insert parts of a log file nginx to database(mysql)

Tags: awk, sed, logs, mysql

I want to insert some parts of my log file to mysql.
This is my log file:

```
195.xx.x.x - - [25/Apr/2017:09:60:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=contacts&a=form&...
192.xx.x.x - - [25/Apr/2017:09:45:xx +0200] "POST /usery/index.php?m=customer&doajax=request&action=getContacts...
197.xx.x.x - - [25/Apr/2017:09:20:xx +0200] "GET /userx/index.php?m=meeting&doajax=date&id=3
```

In my database I have the columns `[idLog] [date] [user] [module] [action] [doAjax] [ajaxAction]`

Where:
25/Apr/2017--> date 
userx      --> user 
m=xxx -->module 
a=xxx -->action 
doajax=xxx-->doAjax 
action=xxx-->ajaxAction 
idLog is auto increment

So I need to insert of my logfile that information:

```
INSERT INTO logs VALUES('null',25/04/2017,usery,contacts,form,null,null)
INSERT INTO logs VALUES('null',25/04/2017,usery,customer,null,request,getContacts)
INSERT INTO logs VALUES('null',25/04/2017,userz,meeting,null,date,null)
```

I want to insert the date that is on the 4th column and some parts of the request that is 7th column (`/userx/index.php?m=meeting&doajax=date&id=3`) that are in my date base.
Some ideas?...

I tried to create a script bash using `awk` and `sed` for to cut some parts of my log file and for to insert to my data base

Answer (score 0):

If the fields position are constant eg : if date always in 2nd Field. Then you can use for loop to process file lines and use awk to get the required field and assign to a variable. Within the loop echo the insert query with variable values of date etc to a file.. and finally execute all insert query in once.